# strange new Date in deepEqual

Tags: node.js, assert, deepequals

I have this code

```
var assert = require('assert');

describe('date', function() {
  it('deep equal', function() {
    assert.deepEqual({date: ''}, {date:new Date()});
  });
});
```

when I run the test with mocha I get this

```
  AssertionError: { date: '' } deepEqual { date: 2017-03-08T21:58:45.767Z }
  + expected - actual

   {
  -  "date": ""
  +  "date": [Date: 2017-03-08T21:58:45.767Z]
   }

  at Context.<anonymous> (test/test_date.js:5:12)
```

Why the date generated in the deepEqual have this format `[Date: 2017-03-08T21:58:45.767Z]` and not this format `2017-03-08T21:58:45.767Z` ?

Why the date generated is between the brackets `[Date: ...]` ?

Comment: What's wrong with delimiters around a value representation? There is no standardised serialisation format

Comment: @Bergi the problem with the delimiter is: I have a function who return a date, and I try to test the output of the function, I can fake the clock with sinon http://sinonjs.org/releases/v1.17.7/fake-timers/, and when I try to test a expected date string is different to the date generated in the assert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that this is the way your testing suite shows you that the object is an instance of the `Date` class. You would not get this information if it were simply `2017-03-08T21:58:45.767Z`, and would possibly be harder to debug in a more complex scenario.

In the first line,

```
  AssertionError: { date: '' } deepEqual { date: 2017-03-08T21:58:45.767Z }
```

It's showing the `toISOString()` representation, but this could be misleading because the value of `date` is **not** that string. The value is a `Date` object, so in the diff it makes that clear.